# How to add a button in titlebar using swift in coca(OS X application)

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

How can I add a button on title bar and add its action for a desktop application in `swift`. Unfortunately I don't have any knowledge in Objective C. I am using Xcode 6. Any help is great!